# What is causing Xorg high CPU usage?

Tags: cpu, xorg, xserver

I am running feh image viewer on Debian and after some hours of normal CPU usage (3% aprox.) , xorg suddenly starts using much more CPU (80% aprox.) and everything runs very slowly. I am not running anything else so the bug should be either on feh or on the xserver...

I am using the command "feh -z -q -D20 -R 1" (-z for random image, -q for quiet, -D20 to change the picture every 20 seconds and -R 1 to refresh the directory every second, as I erase and insert pictures pretty often)

When I use the command "free -m" before the high CPU usage and feh running, I get
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            923         117         474          19         331         735
Swap:            99           0          99

And after several hours I get the same for "mem" but the used amount of "swap" is 99.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your memory usage goes up (swap is full) points directly to memory leak in some program in your system. Considering that `feh` is not probably designed for such an use case I'd bet it's the cause for going out of memory.

The "everything runs slowly" is caused by kernel going out of memory and it's doing its best to keep the system running. If you insist on runnin `feh` your choices are

- Triage the memory leak bug in `feh` and create a fix for it.
- Try to get somebody else do the same for you.
- Periodically kill `feh` and rerun it again. Basically you can do (in `bash`)

  `while true; do timeout 120m feh -z -q -D20 -R 1; sleep 2s; done`

  which will kill every 120 min and restart it after 2 second delay (which allows you to kill the `while` loop if needed). Another choice would be to use `ulimit` to set maximum amount of memory you want to allow for `feh` and the process probably simply dies once it's using too much.

Comment: Note that `ulimit` typically cannot enforce memory usage limits on modern Linux and you have to use `cgroup` limits instead. Something like `systemd-run --scope --user -p MemoryAccounting=yes -p MemoryLimit='100M' feh ...` should work with modern Linux distributions.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue: 25% CPU load (i.e., one full core ) shown by `top` for `Xorg`.
In my case, this went away on restarting `xfce4-panel`.

Answer (score 1):

In the future (October 2023 :-), Xorg high CPU utilization will also occur when running Xorg with Compiz.

My scenario: Eight days after logging in, the Xorg process was 1.1GiB and consuming 50%-100% of a core. [I didn't think to check the compiz process; see below.]

Workaround:

- In MATE Tweak, in the "Windows" section, change the window manager from Compiz to eg. Marco(picom:Hybrid), then wait for the change to complete.  At this point there's no longer a compiz process, and Xorg is at 126MiB RAM and 7% CPU.
- If like me you really want Compiz, change the window manager back to Compiz.  Xorg is still at 126MiB RAM but now 27% CPU.  Compiz is at 66MiB RAM and 26% CPU.  I don't know whether these higher loads are expected, but I'll investigate that separately.

Now to address the zombie in the room:
I replied here (despite the age of this thread) because it's the second-highest result for a DuckDuckGo search for "ubuntu xorg high cpu usage"; I hope that my finding may help someone else.

Answer (score -4):

I solved this problem, but I don't know why, too.

You can try run this code kill this process:

```sh
ps -a | grep Xorg | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill 9
```

Comment: Hmm, i.e. killall -9 Xorg

Comment: That will kill the X server, ending your X session and leaving all your GUI programs to exit somehow.  It's somewhat similar to logging out, but without gracefully terminating some of the clients.